# Dynamically access property with typecasting in TypeScript with generic

Tags: typescript, generics, type-conversion

I have following simplified function that accept generic.

```
function filter<T>(data: T[]) {
    
    const filter = { field: 'name', type: 'string', condition: 'ct' }

    data.forEach((value) => {
    
        type DataPropertyValue = keyof typeof value
    
        // Following does not work 
        // const dynamicValue = (value[filter.field as DataPropertyValue] as String).toLowerCase() --- This does not work
        // const dynamicValue = value[filter.field as DataPropertyValue].toLowerCase() --- This does not work
    
        // But this works but I have to re-instantiate String here
        const dynamicValue = String(value[filter.field as DataPropertyValue]).toLowerCase()
        console.log(dynamicValue)
    })
}
```

This works but as you see I have to recreate instance of `String` to operate on the value. Is there anyway to do this without re-instantiating `String` again.

Comment: The errors are there for a reason; the compiler is telling you that `filter.field` might not be a key of `data`'s elements, and that even if it is, the property value at that key might not be a `string`.  What do you want to happen if someone calls `filter([null])` or `filter(["oops"])` or `filter([{name: 1}])`?  Why do you want to use type assertions here?  What is the actual goal?

Comment: Given your example as written I'd want to constrain `T` to `{name: string}`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5e02N).  Or possibly allow the filter key to be generic like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDkLzw).  But maybe I'm missing something about the question.  Could you make sure your code here is a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `value` is of type `T`, which could be *anything*. Which means that the property you are trying to look up may not actually have a string type.

For example:

```
filter([{ name: true }])
```

Here `T` would be of type `{ name: boolean }` and `toLowerCase` called on a `boolean` would throw an exception.

---

You could fix this by adding code that checks to make sure the value is the right runtime type before proceeding.

That might look something like this:

```
function filter<T>(data: T[]) {
    
    const filter = { field: 'name', type: 'string', condition: 'ct' }

    data.forEach((value) => {
        const dynamicValue = filter.field in value ? value[filter.field as keyof T] : undefined
        if (typeof dynamicValue === 'string') {
            console.log(dynamicValue.toLowerCase())
        } else {
            console.log('unsupported property type')
        }
    })
}

filter([{ name: true }]) // logs "unsupported property type"
filter([{ name: 'FOO' }]) // logs "foo"
```

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you after, but I think it's closer.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbKBTATgHgCoB8AFACYCGUZAXIngNoC6AlIgN4BQiXin3ECAZyjI0mLIgC8bERlQkaAcjBkAthgUAaRFACeABwyKhWGGADmmxPzAkYsBIugLEAX3a8u5SgDpgcLACiZBAAFkREAG5kqCAYLBIEbB7cXNZCiCQ6yiowEABq0bGSIujYvjCyJIimiFExGIgA-LWFGHQopVjllYhkAogA1hg6cMC0DIg04CQYKGAYJMkpMGNEugajGVmquQX1khJSCsamFiwcKZd8gnCoGN6ocGak2zn5rd5QcAAycADu2AAwn0MEQmEwltwXIhZAIGhcrpc0rd7o9ngpwAIQHo9P5MFU9Fg4AYsLptPp1BDEa5ki4IW52B0xEQ6KxENlDNosEUXMxEAB6fmINH9ABEmOxuNJC0QhOJ2DJ6wwosZomwLLZHMUADEAPK65y8liC4VPMV+OCioA)